# Can Firestore Transactions Be Batched?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a series of updates being performed on a firestore collection query where each update needs to access the current values. I know transactions are the atomic way of doing these updates, but is it possible to batch this series of updates?

Currently, I update the collection like this:

```
let query;
query = db.collection('focuses');
query = query.where('userId', '==', auth.currentUser.uid);
query = query.where('active', '==', true);

query.get().then(snapshot => {
  const batch = db.batch();

  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    batch.update(
      db.collection('focuses').doc(doc.id),
      { 
        active: false, 
        working: true,
        time: doc.data().workPeriod * 60,
      }
    );
  });

  batch.commit().then(() => {
    auth.signOut().catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

This works but the `workPeriod` field is being accessed outside of a transaction, so my understanding is that it could be vulnerable to simultaneous access.

So is it possible to do a transaction for each batch update? If it is not, then is the best approach to collect each `Promise` from the series of transactions and then use `Promise.all` to set up a callback that will be called when the series of transactions has completed?

Answer (score 0):

No, transactions can't be batched.  You have to choose either a batch or a transaction for atomic updates.  A transaction is similar to batch in that all the updates apply, or none of them do.  The difference between a batch and a transaction is that a batch simply writes, but a transaction reads then writes.